# When setting background color to button in android it Hides White Space between buttons in linear layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I am facing problem, when setting background color to button it hides white space between button in a Linear Layout(Vertical)

```
 LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(thisContext);
 for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
 {
      Button b=new Button(thisContext);
      b.setText("Button"+i);
      b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
      ll.addview(b);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(thisContext);
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  Button b=new Button(thisContext);
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams bParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  bParams.setMargins(5,5,5,5);
  b.setLayoutParams(bParams);
  b.setText("Button"+i);
  b.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  ll.addview(b);
}
```